# How to get the output as following by combining data from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, union

so I have 3 tables in my db, where all 3 tables contains a column which have similar data, but name of that column is different on all the 3 tables, below is an example.

**Ban Table**

| user_id | ban_user_id | ban_date | reason | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1300 | 1 | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 32 | 1 | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 43 | 2 | xyz | xyz | xyz |

**Reports Table**

| user_id | last_modified_user_id | report_date | reason | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1300 | 1 | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 32 | 2 | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 43 | 2 | xyz | xyz | xyz |

**Warning Table**

| user_id | warning_user_id | warning_date | reason | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1300 | 1 | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 32 | 2 | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 43 | 3 | xyz | xyz | xyz |

Now I want to fetch data by combining these 3 tables, where ban_user_id, last_modified_user_id, and warning_user_id contains the data of staff member who took the actions, so i want to group the data by the staff id.

**The output i am looking for is as follows:**

| staff_id | total_reports | total_bans | total_warnings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

where it is counting the data for each table by grouping the 2nd column, ban_user_id, last_modified_user_id, warning_user_id respectively. And than combining the data.

I tried things with UNION All and stuffs, but it didn't work out.

Thankyou in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` for all 3 tables and then aggregate:

```
SELECT staff_id,
       COUNT(report) AS total_reports,
       COUNT(ban) AS total_bans,
       COUNT(warning) AS total_warnings
FROM (
  SELECT last_modified_user_id AS staff_id, 1 AS report, null AS ban, null AS warning FROM Reports
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ban_user_id, null, 1, null FROM Ban
  UNION ALL
  SELECT warning_user_id, null, null, 1 FROM Warning
) t
GROUP BY staff_id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT staff_id,
       SUM(report) AS total_reports,
       SUM(ban) AS total_bans,
       SUM(warning) AS total_warnings
FROM (
  SELECT last_modified_user_id AS staff_id, 1 AS report, 0 AS ban, 0 AS warning FROM Reports
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ban_user_id, 0, 1, 0 FROM Ban
  UNION ALL
  SELECT warning_user_id, 0, 0, 1 FROM Warning
) t
GROUP BY staff_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f50eded1fe531cb843675a0bb44e1fd6).

Comment: Wow, works perfectly, thankyou very much. Can you help me understand it a bit, like how this 0, 1 thing working on the select statements.

Comment: @VivekBora each row of the unioned tables contains either 0 or 1 in each column. Take a look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a48cd498681d76a6b010124298b1081 Then these rows are summed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Table joins (Inner/outer/left/right)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to get the data instead of union.
I'm assuming the staff_id is the equivalent of user_id column as you haven't mentioned anything about that, so your script will look something like this:

```
SELECT W.user_id AS staff_id, 
    B.ban_user_id, 
    R.last_modified_user_id, 
    W.warning_user_id
FROM Warning AS W
LEFT JOIN Reports AS R on R.user_id = W.user_id
LEFT JOIN Ban AS B on B.user_id = W.user_id
group by W.user_id
```